# Daylight Saving Time in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dst

I am running my web apps in `UTC+0530` timezone. I want to **find the daylight saving time of `UTC+0000`** time zone. Is it possible in javascript?

Comment: Which country are you interested in, as UTC+0000 is used by several, and not all of them use daylight savings

Comment: could be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887934/check-if-daylight-saving-time-is-in-effect-and-if-it-is-for-how-many-hours but the author is interessed by DST NOT of his country

Comment: http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/ist

Comment: Obligatory explanation of why the only way to do this is to use a recently updated `tzdata`: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY

Comment: You have the cart before the horse.  Time zone offsets do not use daylight saving time, but rather daylight saving time controls how a time zone will *change* its offset.  You need to read [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), especially the section "Time Zone != Offset".

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript only **no**.
The logic to determine if a country XXX is following DST or no can't be calculated by javascript because it's more ... politic.

See also [How to know whether a country is using Daylight Saving Time using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223112/how-to-know-whether-a-country-is-using-daylight-saving-time-using-javascript) which gives a code to theorically calculate what the DST *should* be.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a native javascript way to do this, and perhaps if this is a one-off requirement, then the [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887934/check-if-daylight-saving-time-is-in-effect-and-if-it-is-for-how-many-hours) by @Emmanuel above is right for you.

If you want to perform different types of date manipulation, I would recommend using the [moment.js library](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/).